# How to resize pop up window size when opened from mobile device

Tags: css

I am trying to use a pop up window which is loaded when the screen is displayed. It is working well from desktop but when opening from mobile the size of the pop up is not getting resized. From mobile the entire pop up is not getting displayed. I am providing you the CSS properties which I used.

Can you please help by letting me know how to resize the window to fit the mobile devices as well.

```css
#ac-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
    width: 555px;
    height: 375px;
    background: #9152f8;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 375px;
}
```

How to put values which will resize and fit the screen of the device?

Added this and the viewport in the document head as per the replies but now the pop up would not load at all.

```css
           @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       #ac-wrapper {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
                z-index: 1001;
            }

       #popup {
             width: 555px;
                height: 375px;
                background: #9152f8;
                border: 5px solid #000;
                border-radius: 25px;
                -moz-border-radius: 25px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
                box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
                -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
                position: relative;
                top: 150px;
                left: 375px; 
        }
  }
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code, otherwise we'll be guessing, at best, at why it isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: It's very difficult to actually help you when you don't have a reproduction of the issue for us to view. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have edited the question. The pop up isn't loading at all when I used the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this would be to use [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/), rather than hardcoding your `width` and `height` properties. For example:

```
#popup {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 30vh;
}
```

Another thing you might consider would be to add [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to your css code.

```
#ac-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
  width: 555px;
  height: 375px;
  background: #9152f8;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 375px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #popup {
      width: 400px;
      height: 250px;
   }
}
```

For the best user experience it would probably be wise to use media queries, as that will give you more control.

Comment: Edited the post with the media query. But now the pop up isn't loading at all. Sorry if i am doing anything wrong, I am a core java guy and not into CSS and HTML much

Comment: Did you replace your previous code or add the media query to the end of the file? If you replaced your previous code, what you are essentially telling the browser is that you only want to style the `#popup` id when the screen is under 600px. You'll want to make sure the media query is in addition to your previous code, and then change the `width` and `height` properties to reflect what you want the new values to be on a screen under 600px

Comment: Thanks. But it would be wonderful if you can make changes in my code snippet and copy that with your reply.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of different ways to go about this, personally I'd just use media queries. Just set the width of when you'd like pop-up window to resize.

Something like this:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

       #popup {
            /*new sizes here*/ 
        }
  }
```

Be sure to have this in your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Edited the post with the media query. But now the pop up isn't loading at all. Sorry if i am doing anything wrong, I am a core java guy and not into CSS and HTML much